# PHP - Imap_Open is very slow

Tags: php, imap

I want use the imap_open fonction to check e-mail adresses (Outlook) but I don't understand why this function is very slow ? I start the script with WAMPserver in localhost.

```
<?PHP
$mbox = imap_open("{imap-mail.Outlook.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX","MAIL","PASS");

If($mbox)
{
   echo 'connected';
}
else
{
   echo 'bad connections;
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't have a outlook mailbox to check this, but how slow is slow? And what did you expect? Can you put some numbers to this slowness? I did see [a tip here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/all/poor-performance-with-imap-mailoutlookcom/53b7985f-ea41-4625-9df2-eb3eba77092b), change to **outlook.office365.com**.

Comment: Perhaps it's slow DNS looking up `imap-mail.Outlook.com`?

Comment: nope. DNS Lookup speed of `imap-mail.outlook.com` is under 100ms.

Comment: I tried office365 IMAP domaine and also i use the IP without the DNS but still the problème (the execution time of script is of 7seconds)